# Get Tkinter Window Size

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I get the width and height of a Tkinter window?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You use the `winfo_width` method of the widget to get the actual width. You can use `winfo_reqwidth` to get the size that the widget is requesting, which may be different.

Note that if you call this before the window appears on the screen, you won't get the answer you expect. Tkinter needs to have actually drawn the window before it can know the size. A simple fix if you're trying to get the window size before your program starts is to call the `update` method on the window before trying to get the size.

Answer (score 1):

to create an exact window size you can simple do:
window.geometry("400x400") as an example but you have to make sure it is like a string otherwise it wont work like I have experience

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

While skiibloc's answer is technically correct, there is a better way to do things-

```py
width, height = get_window_size(root) #assuming your canvas or window manager is root.
```

this asks the tk program dynamically what the window dimensions are.

Comment: Where is `get_window_size` defined ?