# How to use winfo_width() (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

There are lot answer on stackoverflow 
that say "to width of the widget one shoud use `winfo_width()`".

e.g. [Get Tkinter Window Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220295/get-tkinter-window-size)

Could anybody point me to what I'm doing wrong?

### My example code:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self._make_new_window()
        print 'self.winfo_width()', self.winfo_width()
        print 'self.text_window.winfo_width()', self.text_window.winfo_width()

    def _make_new_window(self):
        self.text_window = tk.Text(tk.Toplevel(self.master))
        self.text_window.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

### Actual result (printed on commandline):

```
self.winfo_width() 1
self.text_window.winfo_width() 1
```

This is strange because:

- `self.text_window` is definitely not the same size as `self`
- very strange measurement units

### Expected result:

```
self.winfo_width() 30
self.text_window.winfo_width() 100
```

At least something allong these lines.

BTW.
This is on python 2.7.
Help info does not reveal anything usefull.

```
Help on method winfo_width in module Tkinter:

winfo_width(self) method of __main__.App instance
    Return the width of this widget.
```

### EDIT - Solution:

- Size can be retrieved only after window is drawn; It's possible to use `self.update()`)
  ([Get Tkinter Window Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220295/get-tkinter-window-size/4221002#4221002))
- Need to use `self.master.winfo_width()` instead of `self.winfo_width()` for `App`
  (comment from fhdrsdg)

Fixed version looks like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

help(tk.Frame)

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self._make_new_window()
        self.update() # add update
        print 'self.master.winfo_width()', self.master.winfo_width() # use self.master
        print 'self.text_window.winfo_width()', self.text_window.winfo_width()

    def _make_new_window(self):
        self.text_window = tk.Text(tk.Toplevel(self.master))
        self.text_window.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Ouput is:

```
self.master.winfo_width() 108
self.text_window.winfo_width() 404
```

Comment: Oh and you probably want `self.master.winfo_width()` instead of `self.winfo_width()`

Comment: I've updated my answer in the [Get Tkinter Window Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220295/get-tkinter-window-size/4221002#4221002) question to help solve your problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley 1st of all I would like to thank you for the updated answer. 2nd, this question is definitely not a duplicate if you had to specifically amend your answer to address my question (thought this probably doesn't really matter I, my problem is solved)